# jqTransform - combo box selected text color change issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have applied jquery plugin "jqTransform" ( [plugin URL](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) ) on my form. Now my requirement is when user select any dropdown item, selected item color should be changed. Here is the URL of the form [www.clickmeal.imobisoft.eu](http://www.clickmeal.imobisoft.eu) and I have attached the example image as well so you can better understand my requirement.

Please help me in this, I know it needs some tricky jquery code and I am beginner at it.

Following is the example image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color seen now is applied by this css rule (style.css), You can change or remove it:

```
#content_area .order_form .form .show_everything .jqTransformSelectWrapper {
width: 224px !important;
height: 33px;
line-height: 41px;
border: none;
margin-left: -5px;
margin-top: 0;
text-indent: 12px;
font-size: 18px;
color: #dad9d9; /*This needs to be removed or changed*/
font-weight: normal;
border-radius: 14px;
box-shadow: inset 1px 3px 5px #cccccc;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

also add this rule to your css file:

```
 .defaultOption {
     color: #dad9d9;
 }
```

Apart from this add this in your script right after the following.

```
$(function() {
    $('.remember , .show_everything').jqTransform({ imgPath: 'app_themes/images/img/' });
       /*Add start*/

    //Add the default option class initially since the default option wil Show Everything
    $(".show_everything").find('.jqTransformSelectOpen').prev('span').addClass('defaultOption');

    //Bind a click event to the plugin control anchor dropdown
    $(".show_everything div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the span element which shows selected text
        var parent = $(this).closest('.jqTransformSelectWrapper').find('.jqTransformSelectOpen').prev('span');
        //Remove the class
        parent.removeClass('defaultOption');
        //Check if clicked option text matches  the target, if so add the default option class to it.
        if ($(this).text().match(/Show Everything/i)) {
            $(this).closest('.jqTransformSelectWrapper').find('.jqTransformSelectOpen').prev('span').addClass('defaultOption');
        }

    });
    /*Add end*/

});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".show_everything").click(function() {
     $(".show").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YAySS/)** of this

Comment: When I remove the color from "#content_area .order_form .form .show_everything .jqTransformSelectWrapper" the first item in the dropdown "Show Everything" is also turn into black color. I want first item "Show Everything" in gray color all the time.

Comment: Right, but how can I add new rules? I didn't find any property for the dropdown items that I can use for css.

Comment: I will be waiting eagerly. Great Thanks :)

Comment: @AwaisImran DO you have control over the dropdown selection? i mean in the JS source code? SInce it is a text on the same div and no separate identifies we would need to use js to apply the class, on selection.

Comment: Please explain what do you want?

Comment: Yes, Exactly this is what I want. Thank you so much :)